# Mail sent by PHP not being recieved by accounts on Google Apps

Tags: email, g-suite

I've been trying to send mail through PHP's mail() function to a Google Apps email address, along with other email addresses. I've been successful in sending to my email (MobileMe) and Gmail- but email sent to any address hosted on Google Apps fails. It seems as if the emails I send to Google Apps don't even get into the inbox or even spam folder- it simply isn't there.

Normal email works just fine- I can send email from my mail client just fine to the emails on Google Apps.

I also tried using Swift Mailer slong with a SMTP server instead of PHP's mail() function, but still no luck. Help??

Comment: Are you using the smtp server to send from php and from you normal mail client?  If you aren't then that is not a valid test.

Comment: Logs will tell you what happened to the e-mail.

Comment: @nathan Yes, I am using the smtp server to send from php.

Comment: @womble I feel so dumb not to think of that! Feel free to post as answer- that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When diagnosing *any* delivery problem, your first step needs to be to look to your logs.  Most MTAs will log via the `mail` facility of syslog, which by default will end up in either `/var/log/maillog` (on RHEL-derived systems) or `/var/log/mail.log` (Debian-derived systems) -- or quite likely somewhere else entirely on some niche systems.  The exception is Exim, which likes to put things in it's own little world somewhere under `/var/log/exim`.

From there, error messages may or may not be clear, but a subtle use of Google and (at worst) a question here on Server Fault with the error message and context will probably result in a useful outcome.

Answer (score -2):

Gmail is tricky. Make sure you're using the right port. 990 I think. And for the username, it's your ENTIRE email address.

Comment: He's sending to email addresses hosted at google, not using their SMTP service to send messages through.